# What manufacturer is this "double-D" logo?

Tags: identification

This is on an SMT transformer. None of my logo catalogs have it and Google couldn't find it, either. Looks like it could be "D"s with their flats facing each other and with the top arc extending past the face to wrap around the opposing "D"s bottom arc.

[image: Logo image that looks like "D"s with their flats facing each other and with the top arc extending past the face to wrap around the opposing "D"s arc]

[image: Transformer image with above-described logo]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That logo belongs to datatronics, a custom magnetics manufacturer. Here is a [link to their Website.](http://www.datatronics.com/default.asp)